# Using scalar product to show that an angle is right

Tags: linear-algebra

The coordinates of the three points A, B, C are $\space$

$A=\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ -7.5 \\ 4.5\end{bmatrix}$

$B=\begin{bmatrix}5.5 \\ -2.5 \\ 5.5\end{bmatrix}$

$C=\begin{bmatrix}10.5 \\ -5 \\ 5.5\end{bmatrix}$.

I don't know the equation of the scalar product of three three dimensional vectors, but I assume is different than two dimensional vectors. And what does the scalar product of three three dimensional vectors represent ?.
Thanks in advance !.

Comment: So you want to show that the angle between these vectors (pairwise) is $90^\circ$?

Comment: "I don't know the equation of the scalar product of three three dimensional vectors"?? A scalar product is a bilinear form, it has only 2 vectors as arguments. Are you sure you do not  mix up with cross-product? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Answer (score 0):

The equation is actually the same: if you have two vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then their scalar product is: $$\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i$$ where $x_i,y_i$ are the components of the vectors.
The geometrical interpretation is the same regardless of the dimension of the space:
if one of your vectors, for instance $\vec{y}$, has lenght one then the product $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}$ is the lenght of the (orthogonal) projection of $\vec{x}$ over the line paralell to $\vec{y}$. If $\vec{y}$ has arbitrary lenght then $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}$ is the product of the lenght of the projection of  $\vec{x}$ over the line paralell to $\vec{y}$ times the lenght of $\vec{y}$